# Add cell if user selects value according to table

Tags: excel

I have this table1, in which I need cells in Threaten column to be added according to the kind of asset selected (like a copy and paste, but with enough space for the rows). In this table2 are mapped Threatens (Eg. "Gestión de políticas de Seguridad de la Información insuficientes) to Kind of assets ("Procesos") in an Excel Dinamic Table (sorry they are in spanish).

I have nothing done since I don't know where to start.

Table1: [image: tabl1]

Table2:

[image: table2]

Comment: Hi! Both links show the same image. Can you fix this please?

Comment: Welcome. As some advice you should include the image here. Links to elsewhere are not recommended. And add a bit more detail, show what you've tried. I'd downvote this if you were more experienced but you're only new.

Comment: I think you're missing a table that shows the different "Threatens" depending on the Asset (is the asset the ID or activity number, or both together?)  At the very least, I think you're probably looking for something like [`VLookUp()`, or `Index/Match`](https://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-use-index-match-instead-vlookup)...but without more info, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Also, in your asset kind column, you can use data validation to get a dropdown of assets. http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal01.html

Comment: I can't put images here because I'm new, the image is fixed now @AER